# Rails 4 - jQuery: add / remove class only works in certain cases

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, addclass

I've come across this strange occurrence where using the same jQuery works in both my Fiddle as well as the website, but in another case only works in the fiddle.

### HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid instructions instruction-loc-big">
    <div class="specialx btn-group btn-group-s" role="group" style="float: left;">
      <button type="button" class="fixme maxi btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle showing the case that DOESN'T work in my website, but does work in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rnqzdLc9/

...but if I remove the "else" portion, and begin with the class "gly-rotate-45" present, it DOES work in the website to remove the class (shown below)

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid instructions instruction-loc-big">
    <div class="specialx btn-group btn-group-s" role="group" style="float: left;">
      <button type="button" class="fixme maxi btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove gly-rotate-45"></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rnqzdLc9/1/

For the record I've also tried `toggleClass()` and that didn't work either.

Comment: Since your issue is not reproducible it's difficult to give an answer. In Rails most problems with jquery are caused by turbolinks and onload event: have you tried to (temporarily) disable turbolinks and see if it works?

Comment: I tried that with no luck, any other thoughts?

Comment: I added a console log after the if / else and it seems like once I remove the class, I then immediately add the class back.  For some reason it is not exiting the loop

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was loading the same .js file twice causing the loop to execute twice, resulting in what seemed to be no change meanwhile the change DID occur, it was then reversed by the second call.